# Changing settings of normal map intensity

Tags: three.js, mapping, settings, texture-mapping, bump-mapping

i currently have an issue with the correct view of my Normal map in three.js.
It looks like shown in the attachment. I think it is a problem with the setting of the normal-map intensity. Is there a way to differentiate between normal- and bump-map intensity. In another viewer (which offers this differentiation) i could provoke this strange look by raising the intensity of the bump-map intensity. 
I would be thankful for any advice.
Thanks and best wishes
Gerd

[Object with texture and normal map in three.js viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exrS8.jpg)

Comment: What are these "viewers" you speak of? What sort of THREE.Material are you using? MeshPhongMaterial has the properties `bumpMapScale` and `normalMapScale`

Comment: We are using a three.js viewer, and we load an Obj-file combined with one jpg texture map and a jpg normal map. And we do use MeshPhongMaterial with the above properties.